# Python: How to optimize a list result by using less lines? This question is already answered using zip

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have the following list:

```
rows= ['Azuay', '10,658', '195', '12', 'Bolívar', '2,111', '66', '12', 'Cañar', '2,110', '83', '7', 'Carchi', '3,053', '104', '1', 'Chimborazo', '2,516', '315', '119', 'Cotopaxi', '4,575', '281', '61', 'El Oro', '6,477', '466', '185', 'Esmeraldas', '4,271', '216', '51', 'Galápagos', '227', '1', '1', 'Guayas', '22,263', '1,737', '1,651', 'Imbabura', '4,773', '170', '7', 'Loja', '6,227', '222', '44', 'Los Ríos', '4,017', '342', '237', 'Manabí', '11,284', '1,025', '1,033', 'Morona Santiago', '3,008', '22', '0', 'Napo', '1,440', '74', '2', 'Orellana', '1,956', '53', '17', 'Pastaza', '2,258', '60', '15', 'Pichincha', '59,477', '1,789', '242', 'Santa Elena', '1,738', '368', '274', 'Santo Domingo de los Tsáchilas', '5,293', '361', '116', 'Sucumbíos', '2,763', '92', '2', 'Tungurahua', '5,119', '276', '223', 'Zamora Chinchipe', '1,580', '53', '1']

I want to convert it to :

[['Azuay', '10,658', '195', '12'],  ['Bolívar', '2,111', '66', '12'],  ['Cañar', '2,110', '83', '7'],  ['Carchi', '3,053', '104', '1'],  ['Chimborazo', '2,516', '315', '119'],  ['Cotopaxi', '4,575', '281', '61'],  ['Esmeraldas', '4,271', '216', '51'],  ['Galápagos', '227', '1', '1'],  ['Guayas', '22,263', '1,737', '1,651'],  ['Imbabura', '4,773', '170', '7'],  ['Loja', '6,227', '222', '44'],  ['Manabí', '11,284', '1,025', '1,033'],  ['Napo', '1,440', '74', '2'],  ['Orellana', '1,956', '53', '17'],  ['Pastaza', '2,258', '60', '15'],  ['Pichincha', '59,477', '1,789', '242'],  ['Sucumbíos', '2,763', '92', '2'],  ['Tungurahua', '5,119', '276', '223'],  ['Zamora Chinchipe', '1,580', '53', '1']]
```

I am using this code (check down below) to obtain this result; however, I want to optimize it.

```
dict_kv=[]
for i in range(0, len(rows)):
  if (rows[i].strip().isalpha()):  
    dict_kv.append([rows[i],rows[i+1],rows[i+2],rows[i+3]])
    
  
dict_kv.append([rows[92],rows[93],rows[94],rows[95]])  s
      
pprint(dict_kv)
```

Comment: Is it always going to be sequence of 4 items in the sub-sequence (and input data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple `list comprehension`:

```
rows= ['Azuay', '10,658', '195', '12', 'Bolívar', '2,111', '66', '12', 'Cañar', '2,110', '83', '7', 'Carchi', '3,053', '104', '1', 'Chimborazo', '2,516', '315', '119', 'Cotopaxi', '4,575', '281', '61', 'El Oro', '6,477', '466', '185', 'Esmeraldas', '4,271', '216', '51', 'Galápagos', '227', '1', '1', 'Guayas', '22,263', '1,737', '1,651', 'Imbabura', '4,773', '170', '7', 'Loja', '6,227', '222', '44', 'Los Ríos', '4,017', '342', '237', 'Manabí', '11,284', '1,025', '1,033', 'Morona Santiago', '3,008', '22', '0', 'Napo', '1,440', '74', '2', 'Orellana', '1,956', '53', '17', 'Pastaza', '2,258', '60', '15', 'Pichincha', '59,477', '1,789', '242', 'Santa Elena', '1,738', '368', '274', 'Santo Domingo de los Tsáchilas', '5,293', '361', '116', 'Sucumbíos', '2,763', '92', '2', 'Tungurahua', '5,119', '276', '223', 'Zamora Chinchipe', '1,580', '53', '1']
rows = [rows[x:x+4] for x in range(0,len(rows),4)]
print(rows)
```

Output:

```
[['Azuay', '10,658', '195', '12'], ['Bolívar', '2,111', '66', '12'], ['Cañar', '2,110', '83', '7'], ['Carchi', '3,053', '104', '1'], ['Chimborazo', '2,516', '315', '119'], ['Cotopaxi', '4,575', '281', '61'], ['El Oro', '6,477', '466', '185'], ['Esmeraldas', '4,271', '216', '51'], ['Galápagos', '227', '1', '1'], ['Guayas', '22,263', '1,737', '1,651'], ['Imbabura', '4,773', '170', '7'], ['Loja', '6,227', '222', '44'], ['Los Ríos', '4,017', '342', '237'], ['Manabí', '11,284', '1,025', '1,033'], ['Morona Santiago', '3,008', '22', '0'], ['Napo', '1,440', '74', '2'], ['Orellana', '1,956', '53', '17'], ['Pastaza', '2,258', '60', '15'], ['Pichincha', '59,477', '1,789', '242'], ['Santa Elena', '1,738', '368', '274'], ['Santo Domingo de los Tsáchilas', '5,293', '361', '116'], ['Sucumbíos', '2,763', '92', '2'], ['Tungurahua', '5,119', '276', '223'], ['Zamora Chinchipe', '1,580', '53', '1']]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a common-enough pattern that there is an entry in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for it.

```py
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

You would use it as:

```py
result = grouper(rows, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
rows= ['Azuay', '10,658', '195', '12', 'Bolívar', '2,111', '66', '12', 'Cañar', '2,110', '83', '7', 'Carchi', '3,053', '104', '1', 'Chimborazo', '2,516', '315', '119', 'Cotopaxi', '4,575', '281', '61', 'El Oro', '6,477', '466', '185', 'Esmeraldas', '4,271', '216', '51', 'Galápagos', '227', '1', '1', 'Guayas', '22,263', '1,737', '1,651', 'Imbabura', '4,773', '170', '7', 'Loja', '6,227', '222', '44', 'Los Ríos', '4,017', '342', '237', 'Manabí', '11,284', '1,025', '1,033', 'Morona Santiago', '3,008', '22', '0', 'Napo', '1,440', '74', '2', 'Orellana', '1,956', '53', '17', 'Pastaza', '2,258', '60', '15', 'Pichincha', '59,477', '1,789', '242', 'Santa Elena', '1,738', '368', '274', 'Santo Domingo de los Tsáchilas', '5,293', '361', '116', 'Sucumbíos', '2,763', '92', '2', 'Tungurahua', '5,119', '276', '223', 'Zamora Chinchipe', '1,580', '53', '1']
r = np.array(rows).reshape(-1,4).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['Azuay', '10,658', '195', '12'],
 ['Bolívar', '2,111', '66', '12'],
 ['Cañar', '2,110', '83', '7'],
 ['Carchi', '3,053', '104', '1'],
 ['Chimborazo', '2,516', '315', '119'],
 ['Cotopaxi', '4,575', '281', '61'],
 ['El Oro', '6,477', '466', '185'],
 ['Esmeraldas', '4,271', '216', '51'],
 ['Galápagos', '227', '1', '1'],
 ['Guayas', '22,263', '1,737', '1,651'],
 ['Imbabura', '4,773', '170', '7'],
 ['Loja', '6,227', '222', '44'],
 ['Los Ríos', '4,017', '342', '237'],
 ['Manabí', '11,284', '1,025', '1,033'],
 ['Morona Santiago', '3,008', '22', '0'],
 ['Napo', '1,440', '74', '2'],
 ['Orellana', '1,956', '53', '17'],
 ['Pastaza', '2,258', '60', '15'],
 ['Pichincha', '59,477', '1,789', '242'],
 ['Santa Elena', '1,738', '368', '274'],
 ['Santo Domingo de los Tsáchilas', '5,293', '361', '116'],
 ['Sucumbíos', '2,763', '92', '2'],
 ['Tungurahua', '5,119', '276', '223'],
 ['Zamora Chinchipe', '1,580', '53', '1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_kv = [list(x) for x in zip(*[iter(rows)]*4)] # to split rows into chunks of 4
    print("The final result of rows, which is renamed to dict_kv, is:")
    pprint(dict_kv)
```

Comment: I obtained this answer for SoloLearn and it works. Thanks for your answers. I think that all may be work well too.